# how to capture the @input parameter in the child component controller class

Tags: angular, typescript

How to capture the @Input() parameter in the **child component controller class**. I tried to console log it from Constructor and OnInit life cycle event, but it comes as undefined. But id gets properly displayed on the child component html with one way binding

I needed the parameter info to write some custom logic in my child component.

parent.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html'
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
    parameter : any = [1 ,2, 3] ; 
}
```

child.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html'
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() parameter : any ; 
    Constructor() {
        console.log(this.parameter) // prints undefined
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.parameter) // prints undefined
    }
}
```

parent.component.html

```
<app-child [parameter]='parameter' ></app-child>
```

child.component.html

```
{{ parameter }} // prints [1 ,2, 3]
```

Comment: add some example code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see in this plunker of your code you will see that only `constructor` outputs undefined and `ngOnInit` outputs the array `[1, 2, 3]`

Here is a working plunker https://embed.plnkr.co/szRxO7b94r1o15vLbLbl/

**Update for comment**
The plunker now uses a service and a test API and it works fine on parent and child. Uses ngOnChanges so you can work with the response once it's returned. You should read the [lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) like @Günter Zöchbauer mentions in his answer.

Comment: Thanks for the plunkr working sample. I tried setting the same variables and it worked perfectly in my project too and was surprised, then i realized i was  setting the variable inside a subscribe event in my parent component and these variables are coming as undefined (because it is still not assigned as the ngOnInit runs on child component ?)     `this.service.getMethod().subscribe(results => { this.parameter = results });`

Comment: @Sal
I have updated the plunker using a service connecting to test API. If you could share your service also or try and make a plunker that shows your problem.

Comment: @j the plunkr also has the same issue....i am also able to bind it to UI, but not able to capture it in ngOnInit event to work on the object. below is the console data which clearly prints undefined from ngOnInit method. `run.plnkr.co/preview/ciwmjiw2a00093j5nmmxxuks9/src/app.ts!transpiled:52 constructor undefined
run.plnkr.co/preview/ciwmjiw2a00093j5nmmxxuks9/src/app.ts!transpiled:55 ngOnInit undefined`

Comment: @Sal that's because the request for the service hasn't returned the request. The timing for that request all depends on retrieving that data from the api which has many different factors. You will need to subscribe waiting for a change or trigger event when the request has returned successfully to work with the data. What exactly are you trying to do with the returned data in the child?

Comment: @sal If you look at the updated plunker you will see that ngOnChanges would accomplish what you require.

Comment: @j Perfect, that solved the problem. I was trying to create some models for binding in my child object, based my data from parent object, I could have done the same from my parent and send it directly for binding, but i thought since this is specific to the child object, its better to write the logic in child component itself. Am I thinking right or is there any better way to accomplish the same?

Comment: @Sal I'm glad that fixed it. Yes if the child is where the logic is only going to be used then it is best to have that in the child.

Answer (score 2):

`@Input()`s are not yet set when the constructor is executed.

When change detection runs and updates `@Input()`s `ngOnChanges()` is called.

After `ngOnChanges()` was called the first time, `ngOnInit()` is called.

For more details about lifecycle methods see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html

Answer (score 0):

As people say before you should get parameter values in ngOnInit()

And two details: you don't need use 'implements OnInit', and write ' constructor()' using small 'c' letter at the beginning.